# Windows 8 and Oracle Java JDK 7u9 - "This application is not compatible"

Tags: java, windows-8, compatibility

I have never seen this error on WIndows 8 so far, that's why I'm asking for help here.
First of all, I managed to install JDK 7u7. The installer worked like a charm, and my Java applications run too. But I thought I should upgrade to u9. And that's where I am now.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: I'm using Start8 (left-bottom), but that's not relevant here I guess. As you can see, Avast is also turned off, as it caused problems at the NetBeans install. And that's all I guess. || Removing the previous versions and running the installer again didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, the file sizes for the 32 and 64-bit JDK 7 u9 versions seem to be ~66.14 and ~70.72 MB respectively. I just checked the site and here's what's listed:

```
Windows x86     88.35 MB    jdk-7u9-windows-i586.exe  
Windows x64     90.03 MB    jdk-7u9-windows-x64.exe
```

Looks like you may have ended up with a broken download/partial file (you can clearly see that u7 seems to be bigger than u9) which could be the source of the error. Re-download and try again.